# Nested foreach returns ONLY the last element of array

Tags: php, xml, xpath, foreach

This function takes an array of strings. For every string, it searches an xml document and returns an array. It appends every array found in a separate array $finalarray.
I am trying to store the search results of the sample.xml file in the $finalarray array. It always stores the search result of the last element (the 3rd value, 'c') for some reason. I also tried with for loop to no avail. For some reason, the xpath query search is reset and will be applied to the last element.

```
// array to capture xml search result
$sampleflightdataxml = simplexml_load_file('sample.xml');
$flightList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$temparray = [];
$finalarray = [];
$xmlres = [];

foreach ($flightList as $flight) {
  $xmlres = $sampleflightdataxml->xpath("//flights/FlightOrigin[contains(text(), '{$flight}')]/ancestor::flights | //flights//FlightDest[contains(text(), '{$flight}')]/ancestor::flight");
  if (count($xmlres) > 0) { // if flight data is found
    foreach ($xmlres as $key => $val) {
      $temparray[$key]['FlightOrigin'] = (string)$val->FlightOrigin;
      $temparray[$key]['FlightDest'] = (string)$val->FlightDest;
    }
    $finalarray[] = $temparray;
  
  }
  
}
return $finalarray;
```

Comment: Could you provide us a sample of the XML file? Did you try debugging with *XDebug* or with a few `var_export()` or `print_r()` commands as a start?

Comment: I think you should replace the `|` operator by `or` because the first operator is bitwise and I asume you want it logical/boolean instead.

Comment: Also, is `contains()` what you want? What happens if one flight origin is "Santiago de los Caballeros" ? It actually contains a `a`, `b` and `C`. I imagine that the list of flights is probably not letters but words. In this case it may be better to use the `=` operator. And if it has to be case-insensitive I would also use the `lower-case()` function.